# Clearing setinterval not working?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

```
var theintrvl = function() {
  setInterval(function () {
     somefunction()
  }, 3000)
}
```

the `somefunction` isn't important - all works just fine, BUT! When I try to clear the interval it doesn't clear. Here's what I tried:

```
document.getElementById('clearme').addEventListener('click', function() {
   clearInterval(theintrvl);
});
```

I also tried `somefunction` instead the `theintrvl`, but nothing!

Comment: You must store the intervalID returned by the setInterval call. Right now you are storing a function

Comment: var test = setInterval(function () {
     somefunction()
  }, 3000);
clearInterval(test);

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to wrap it in a function at first place. Just save the value returned by `setInterval` function

```
var theintrvl = 
  setInterval(function () {
     somefunction()
  }, 3000);
```

Comment: Or don't wrap it in an anonymous function in the first place.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek actually, the anonymous function wasn't invoke itself. so `theintrvl` was simply having a function reference, not the interval timer.

Comment: So why are you still wrapping `somefunction` in an anonymous function?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I am not anymore, setInterval return value is directly going to `theintrvl`

Comment: @Bergi It doesn't really matter in that case, although it would be cleaner to just state `setInterval(somefunction, 3000)`.

Comment: gurvinder372! THANKS man! BTW: if I wanna go back to the interval, how should I properly call it? I tried this but it didn't work: `document.getElementById('restartit').addEventListener('click', function() {
  theintrvl();
});`

Comment: @trouuiau if you want to be able to clear the timer later on then you need to call setInterval directly rather than wrapping it inside a function

Answer (score 2):

You need to have

```
var myinterval = setInterval(function, time)
```

And then to clear it you would do

```
clearInterval(myinterval)
```

You may want to get rid of the outside function though because `myinterval` wouldn't be accessable from outside `theintervl`

One more thing, you might consider doing

```
setInterval(somefunction, 3000)
```

Instead of calling the function from an anonymous function

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var test = setInterval(somefunction, 3000);
 clearInterval(test);
```